# What is the best IDE and language for web development to build cutting edge websites?

Tags: ide, programming-languages

I recently got interested in web development coming from kernel based applications. I am curious to what the best development environment and language that one can use to build a nice looking website. I have a distant familiarity with PHP, CSS and the like but I am comfortable with HTML.

Comment: All of them, and none of them at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be perfectly frank: it doesn't really matter.

As long as it produces useful HTML, CSS, and perhaps JavaScript, you can have a beautiful website (and you can also produce bad websites!). The development environment is purely a matter of taste for the programmers.

As long as you are disciplined and attack the project with a plan, know a good designer or two, and have the will power to see it through till the end, you'll be successful.

Comment: +1 There isn't a development environment or language that's going to overcome ugly design.

Comment: +1 The specific technology is usually the least of the issues, and will not resolve poor design. Ever.

Comment: Using the language/ide that one is most familiar with will make it easier (and faster) to create the site.

Comment: thanks guys - Design & plan is the key. got it